# Some basic subdifferential computations

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-smooth-analysis, non-smooth-optimization

I'm trying to understand a bit of nonsmooth analysis, but I'm struggling even to compute a simple example. Any help would be awesome!

Could you please confirm how do the subdifferentials of these functions look like at $x=0$?

- $f_1(x)\doteq\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & \text{if } x= 0 \\ 1, & \text{otherwise.} \end{array}\right.$
- $f_2(x)\doteq x+f_1(x)$.
- $f_3(x)\doteq\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & \text{if } x= 0 \\ \infty, & \text{otherwise.} \end{array}\right.$
- $f_4(x)\doteq x+f_3(x)$.

By the definition $\partial f(x)\doteq \{s\in \mathbb{R}\colon f(y)\geq f(x) + s(y-x), \ \forall y\in \mathbb{R}\}$, it seems to me that $\partial f_1(0)=\{0\}$, $\partial f_2(0)=\{1\}$ and $\partial f_3(0)=\partial f_4(0)=\mathbb{R}$. Am I correct?

Probably not, because of these two apparent contradictions:

- The point $x=0$ is a local minimizer of $f_2$, which would imply that $0\in \partial f_2(0)$, right? But this seems not to be the case.
- It seems to me, intuitively, that $\partial f_1(0)$ and $\partial f_3(0)$ should coincide, which does not seem to be the case, either.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are correct. Your concerns are not.

> The point $x=0$ is a local minimizer of $f_2$, which would imply that $0\in \partial f_2(0)$, right? But this seems not to be the case.

The subgradient you are considering is the global subgradient, not one of the local generalisations. Consequently, $x = 0$ would have to be a **global** minimiser in order for $0 \in \partial f_2(0)$. This, of course, is not the case, e.g. $f_2(-2) = -1 < 0 = f_2(0)$.

> It seems to me, intuitively, that $\partial f_1(0)$ and $\partial f_3(0)$ should coincide, which does not seem to be the case, either.

You may need to adjust your intuition. Remember, you're looking for slopes of (sub)tangent lines through $(0, f_i(0))$ that lie below the graph of $f_i$. In the case of $f_1$, the subtangent is very restricted by the line $y = 1$ which forms most of the graph of $f_1$, to the point where the subtangent is forced to be parallel.

This is not the case in $f_3$. Instead, we have removed that part of the graph, so the subtangent can take any slope.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please point some of the local generalizations that make $0\in \partial f(x)$ necessary for the local optimality of $x$? By the way, do you have any reference recommendation on nonsmooth optimization for someone who only took an introductory course on convex analysis?

Comment: @Myth For your first question, [relevant MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139142/an-intuition-for-three-different-types-of-subgradients-proximal-regular-limit). For your second question, you can check out the standard: Rockerfellar and Wets' book called *Variational Analysis*. I mostly use it as a reference, so I can't necessarily vouch for how easy it is to read without much background. I suspect it should be fine though.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for you help!